# android: create a shortcut in the launcher that is sent to a service or a broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, shortcut

As far as I experienced, a shortcut installed on a homescreen (see INSTALL_SHORTCUT intent) can only start an activity. I have not found a way for the intent to be received by a Service or BroadcastReceiver of my app.

Thing is, the shortcut should just be a small action (here: start a timer) popping up a toast. Right now, if the app is running, it is activated - and I do not need or even want this.

Answer (score 1):

> I have not found a way for the intent to be received by a Service or BroadcastReceiver of my app.

That is because this is not supported.

> the shortcut should just be a small action (here: start a timer) popping up a toast

You can have the shortcut point to an activity using `Theme.NoDisplay`. That activity can start your timer, show your `Toast`, and call `finish()`, all from `onCreate()` and all without calling `setContentView()`. Or, the `Theme.NoDisplay` activity can call `startService()` or `sendBroadcast()`, then call `finish()`, from `onCreate()` without calling `setContentView()`.

In either case, you do not have a UI (other than perhaps the `Toast`), yet still have an activity to satisfy the shortcut requirements.

> Right now, if the app is running, it is activated - and I do not need or even want this.

You may need to play around with manifest settings for the `Theme.NoDisplay` activity to get it to be in a different task.

Comment: Gee, that was fast ;) Well I tried it that way, still the main activity is started. "android:process", "android:launchmode": all checked and it di not help. So yes, I receive the intent in a "NoDisplay" app just for that purpose, still the least recently used activity is popping up when the onCreate() finishes.

Comment: @chksr: Try `android:taskAffinity`: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#aff